# Raise Pylint Warning to Error

Tags: python, pylint

I am finding a lot of silly errors related to undefined variable names in some Python code. If I run pylint, these are picked up as "warnings", which is OK but it would be much better if I could force them to be marked as "errors", as then they would be highlighted in the IDE (Visual Studio).

Is there any way to configure pylint in the .pylintrc file so that "undefined-variable" is treated as an error not a warning?

Thanks

Comment: 'undefined variable' is an error (E0602), do you mean 'unused' ?

Comment: Pylint still reports it in the output file as ": warning:". That's what I need to change